# ef code first seed many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a many to many relationship.

a tag can have multiple articles and an article can have multiply tags.

```
public class Article : Entity
{
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Content { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
public class Tag : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

the ef codefirst creates a table called `TagArticles` with columns `Tag_Id` and `Article_Id`

I tried to seed like this

```
    protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        var articles = new List<Article>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            articles.Add(new Article { Name = "test " + i,  Content = "lourm ipsum"  });
        }
        var tags = new List<Tag>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tags.Add(new Tag { Name = "tag " + i , Articles = new  Article[]{ articles[0] }});
        }
        context.Articles.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name, articles.ToArray());
        context.Tags.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name, tags.ToArray());
    }
```

but the TagArticles table is empty after the migration, how do I seed the bridge table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you had above worked for me when I put it in, but I had to add the Primary Keys in order for the database to actually save.

Where are you setting the primary keys?  Is that in the Entity inheritance?

After you seed, are there Articles and Tags in the database (there wasn't for me until I corrected the PK issue)

Comment: Mark you are right, it does work and yes Entity has an Id. I double checed and it did work for me. I did ad a context.SaveChanges() to the end.   thanks